# Is it normal for service methods to correlate to your views?

Tags: domain-driven-design, services

I've been working on learning how to implement domain services and view models in my project and have noticed a suspicious trend:

When obtaining data for views from my controllers, if my domain services are producing view models, I end up with one service method for each view model being requested.

I'm wondering if perhaps there's something that I might have misunderstood in how/where I create view models?  Should I be creating a special set of services in my project that compose my more inner domain services to build view models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service methods correlate with individual *services.*  If the purpose of the service is to provide data for display in a UI, then you're also going to have a corresponding View Model.  But that's not the only thing that a service method can provide.

Comment: Of course.  I didn't mean to imply I was only using them for view models.  Although, based on what you said, I guess what I might be doing wrong here is trying to have domain services that also facilitate view models.  What I should be doing is creating a separate bunch of services only for making the view models?

Comment: Sure, if that makes sense for your particular application's requirements specification.

Answer (score 0):

The View model is a different bounded context from your domain model.
So you need a context map to map between them.

Your domain services should produce domain entities and value objects. The mapping to view models is a different responsability. If the domain service would produce view models, it cannot be reused.